# SwiftUI dynamically add items to List

Tags: swift, list, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI. I'm just wondering how I could insert new items to my List by using the function addRestaurant. restaurants.append() ... is not working in addRestaurant. The list should be refreshing the items as a user hits the button.

Here is the code so far:

```
import SwiftUI
    
    
     
    struct Restaurant: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let name: String
        let stars: String
    }
    
    struct RestaurantRow: View {
        var restaurant: Restaurant
    
        var body: some View {
            HStack
            {
                Image(systemName: "photo")
                Text("\(restaurant.name)")
                Text("Stars \(restaurant.stars)").foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
            }
            
             
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView: View {
         @State var restaurants = [
            Restaurant(name: "Joe's Original", stars: "5"),
            Restaurant(name: "The Real Joe's Original", stars: "4"),
            Restaurant(name: "Original Joe's", stars: "3")
        ]
        
        
    
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView{
                List(restaurants)
                { restaurant in
                    RestaurantRow(restaurant: restaurant)
                }
                .navigationBarItems(
                    trailing: Button(action: addRestaurant, label: { Text("Add")}))
                .navigationTitle("Table View Playground")
            }.refreshable {
                restaurants.append(Restaurant(name: "Joe's", stars: "2"))
                
                
            }
            
        }
    }
     
    
    func addRestaurant(){
         
         
        
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addRestaurant()` needs to be contained within the `ContentView` struct. Otherwise, you do not have access to the `restaurants` variable that was created in `ContentView`. This is referred to as the scope of the variable. You can only access it within its own scope, so, if defined in a struct, it is only available within the struct. Google Swift/SwiftUI scope and you will find a great deal of information. Therefore, your code would change to:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var restaurants = [
        Restaurant(name: "Joe's Original", stars: "5"),
        Restaurant(name: "The Real Joe's Original", stars: "4"),
        Restaurant(name: "Original Joe's", stars: "3")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(restaurants)
            { restaurant in
                RestaurantRow(restaurant: restaurant)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing: Button(action: addRestaurant, label: { Text("Add")}))
            .navigationTitle("Table View Playground")
        }.refreshable {
            addRestaurant()
        }
    }
    func addRestaurant(){
        restaurants.append(Restaurant(name: "Joe's", stars: "2"))
    }
}
```